# In a random sequence of numerals, find the average spacing between random occurrences of a particular subsequence

Tags: probability

Imagine there is a sequence of base-4 numerals. The sequence is random but different numbers have different probabilities of occurring.  $a$ and $b$ each have a probability of $40$%, $c$ and $d$ each have a probability of $10$%.

Thus, for any $4$ consecutive numerals, the sub-sequence $X = [abcd]$ has probability $\frac {2}{5}\frac {2}{5}\frac {1}{10}\frac {1}{10} = \frac{1}{625}$ of occurring. Since the probability of $X$ occurring is $\frac{1}{625}$, the next occurrence of it, to my reckoning, should on average begin at the $625$th numeral following the former occurrence. Ie, $[a,b,c,d,n_1,n_2,...n_{624},a,b,c,d]$. Thus, it would seem that the average distance between $X$s is $624$.

I only ask because my genetics module has the answer to a similar question as $625$ rather than $624$. I'm skeptical that that's correct, and if it is then I'm missing something. Maybe they count $[abcdabcd]$ as having  'spacing' of $1$, but that seems semantically wrong to me.

Comment: I think it's a question of definition. I would define abcdabcd to be a spacing of 4 because the 2nd abcd is 4 numerals to the right of the 1st abcd. I really think we're arguing about vocabulary, not Mathematics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, since the probability of $X$ occurring is $1/625$, the next occurrence of it, on average, *ends* at the 625th numeral following the former occurrence, i.e., $[a,b,c,d,n_1,n_2,\dots,n_{621},a,b,c,d]$. Thus, the average distance between $X$'s is 621.

---

**Update:**

Here's a derivation.
If you are interested in different methods for solving such  problems, I suggest
 looking at these Math Stack Exchange questions on 
[coin tossing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18405/a-question-related-to-two-competing-patterns-in-coin-tossing) and 
[random bits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27989/time-until-a-consecutive-sequence-of-ones-in-a-random-bit-sequence), 
and also the references at the end of this post.

To solve your problem, we need to consider
four related versions of the game.
In any version, we keep adding a randomly selected letter $\{a,b,c,d\}$
 to the sequence until we see a new occurrence of the pattern $abcd$.
The added letters are represented by the $*$s below.
The letters to the left of $\,|\,$ can be used
as *part* of the new pattern, but we only start counting after $\,|\,$.

$$\begin{array}{lrl}
\mbox{version 1}:& a\,|***\cdots  \\
\mbox{version 2}:& a\,b\,|***\cdots  \\
\mbox{version 3}:& a\,b\,c\,|***\cdots  \\
\mbox{version 4}:& a\,b\,c\,d\,|***\cdots  \\
\end{array}
$$

For example, in version 2 of the game, if the values to
the right of $\,|\,$ are $cd\dots$, then the game ends at $2$ steps.
Alternatively, if the values to
the right of $\,|\,$ are $bdabdcdabcd\dots$, then the game ends at $11$ steps.

Because the pattern $abcd$ has no overlaps, "version 4" is the
same as "version 0", i.e., an initial $d$, $cd$, or $bcd$
are all useless, so it's the same as starting from scratch.
This is the version  you are interested in.

For $1\leq i\leq 4$, let $e_i$ be the expected number of additional
steps to see  $abcd$ again, using version $i$. Then first-step analysis gives the equations:

$$\begin{array}{ll}
e_1 &= 1+2e_1/5 + 2e_2/5 + e_4/5 \\
e_2 &= 1+2e_1/5 + e_3/10 +e_4/2 \\
e_3 &= 1+2e_1/5 + e_4/2         \\
e_4 &= 1+2e_1/5 + 3e_4/5        \\
\end{array}$$

Let me explain the top row; the others are similar.
We are playing version 1 of the game. The $1+$ on the right
hand side comes from the first step. If the first letter is  $a$ ($p=2/5$),
then we are back to version 1. If it is  $b$ ($p=2/5$), we have
made some progress and are now in version 2.
If it is either $c$ or $d$ ($p=1/5$) then we have to start over, and
are in version 4.

The linear algebra problem above has solution
$$[e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4]=[1245/2, 2475/4, 1125/2, 625]$$
which gives $e_4=625$.

**Note:** Having gone through a full derivation, I ought to mention that if your pattern has *no overlaps* (like $abcd$), then it is not necessary to go through all these calculations. The expected number of trials to get the pattern is simply 1 over the probability of occurrence. If there *are* overlaps, you have to work a bit harder.

---

**References**

1. Sections 3.6.4, 7.9.1., and example 4.22. of
   *Introduction to Probability Models (10th edition)* by Sheldon M. Ross.
2. Section 8.4 of  *Concrete Mathematics (2nd edition)* by Ronald Graham, Donald Knuth, and Oren Patashnik
3. Section 1.4 and Chapter 14 of
   *Problems and Snapshots from the World of Probability* by Gunnar Blom, Lars Holst,
   and Dennis Sandell.

Comment: Any chance you can post the derivation? Because I don't see how that's correct. Imagine the probability was $1/3$, then by the above logic, the next occurrence should, on average, end on the $3$rd numeral. But that's not possible because then the two occurrences would be overlapping, and in a way that is not possible, because it would imply that the overlapping numeral would simultaneously be an $a$ and a $d$.

Comment: If $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ are non-negative numbers with $p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4=1$, then by the AM-GM inequality we have $p_1p_2p_3p_4\leq (1/4)^4=1/256$. The chance is always less than $1/3$. I'll try to add something about the derivation later, if I have time.

Comment: @MattMunson By the way, it's good to be skeptical!

Comment: Ok, I see what your saying. I guess what is mainly hanging me up is that if we know that the sequence starts as $abcd$, it seems like we can assign the next $3$ blocks of $4$ a prob. of $0$ because we know they can't form the sequence, and that therefore the distance should be calculated starting after those $3$, giving $624$. Whereas if our sequence was $aaaa$ or $abab$ then you could have sequences overlapping, shortening the average distance.

Comment: Very awesome method. Thank you for taking the time to post it. Now I only wish that I could know the flaw in my reasoning; clearly I was wrong, but I don't see where exactly the error lies.