# Expected length of generating a pattern (throwing dice)

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, markov-chains, dice

A fair die is tossed repeatedly. 
The experiment ends as soon as the last six outcomes form the pattern 131131

What is the expected length (i.e. the number of rolls of the die) of this experiment?

Comment: I remember that the geometric distribution is used to calculate the first occurence, but I'm not sure how to apply it here. Obviously the probability for both a 1 and a 3 is 1/6

Comment: Maybe you should start with simpler problems.  What is the expected number of rolls until a 1 appears? What is the expected number of rolls until the sequence 13 appears? Can you do those?

Comment: E(x) = 1/p and p = 1/6, so the expected number of rolls until a 1 appears is 6. For 13, p is 1/6^2, so the expected number of rolls is 36

Comment: So, what is stopping you from doing the 131131 problem?  Consider, though, the expected number until you get 66: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192177/how-many-times-to-roll-a-die-before-getting-two-consecutive-sixes/192211#192211

Comment: In case my assumption was correct, the expected length of the experiment is 6^6=46656. Right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11852/discussion-between-matthew-conroy-and-bogus)

Answer (score 5):

Conway's algorithm would compare identical terms on the left and right of `131131`:

- length $1$: yes `1` both sides
- length $2$: no `13` on left, `31` on right
- length $3$: yes `131` both sides
- length $4$: no `1311` on left, `1131` on right
- length $5$: no `13113` on left, `31131` on right
- length $6$: yes `131131` both sides

So you have yes for $1$, $3$ and $6$, and $6$ faces on a die so the expected time is $6^1+6^3+6^6=46878$

Comment: This answer is so elegant. Thank you for the share, you also made me look up Conway's work!

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would add my solution to this here as well, in case it may help others. There are other ways to do this. One is a way to do this using Markov Chains. This will work even in cases when the dice is not a fair dice.

Markov Chain Method

You can construct the chain as follows (I just used different colors to disambiguate):

[image]

Let state 0 be nothing i.e. similar to starting afresh.

Note that state 131131 is absorbent i.e. $P($state 131131 to state 131131$)\ = 1$.

Let $\psi(i)$ be the expected number of throws to reach state 131131 from state $i$

We now have equations as follows:

$\psi(13113) = 1 + \frac{5}{6}\psi(0)$

$\psi(1311) = 1 + \frac{1}{6}\psi(1) + \frac{4}{6}\psi(0) + \frac{1}{6}\psi(13113)$

$\psi(131) = 1 + \frac{1}{6}\psi(13) + \frac{4}{6}\psi(0) + \frac{1}{6}\psi(1311)$

$\psi(13) = 1 + \frac{5}{6}\psi(0) + \frac{1}{6}\psi(131)$

$\psi(1) = 1 + \frac{1}{6}\psi(1) + \frac{4}{6}\psi(0) + \frac{1}{6}\psi(13)$

$\psi(0) = 1 + \frac{5}{6}\psi(0) + \frac{1}{6}\psi(1)$

Solve the system of equations for $\psi(0)$ i.e. the expected number of throws to reach 131131 from state 0. You will get:

$\psi(0)=46878$

**Extra**

Additionally, if you want a bunch of intermediate results, you get:

$\psi(1)=46872$

$\psi(13)=46842$

$\psi(131)=46656$

$\psi(1311)=45576$

$\psi(13113)=39066$