# Expected number of flips for $THT$ sequence

Tags: probability, statistics

A Coin with Probability of heads $p$ is continously flipped till the sequence $THT$ occurs.Find the Expected number of coin flips.

My Try: if $X$ is number of coin flips till  $THT$ occurs, $X$ can take values of $3$, $4$,$5$,$\cdots$

$$P(X=3)=(1-p)^2p$$

For $X=4$ the Sample space is $HTHT$ or $TTHT$

$$P(X=4)=(1-p)^2p$$

For $X=5$ the Sample space is $HHTHT$ or $HTTHT$ or $TTTHT$

$$P(X=5)=(p^2-p+1)(1-p)^2p$$ But i feel the process becomes tedious as $X$ increases. Please suggest me any hint...

Comment: See this answer also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596785/expected-length-of-generating-a-pattern-throwing-dice

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the set of prefixes of the word $tht$, that is, the set $\{o,t,th,tht\}$ where $o$ denotes the empty prefix. For every prefix $w$ let $m_w$ denote the mean number of draws needed to produce the word $tht$ starting from a sequence of draws which ends by $w$ but not by any longer prefix.

Thus, $m_{tht}=0$ and the question is to compute $m_o$. Let $q=1-p$.
The usual one-step decomposition yields the identities $$
m_o=1+pm_o+qm_t,\quad m_t=1+pm_{th}+qm_t,\quad m_{th}=1+pm_o,
$$
and solving this affine system yields
$$
m_o=\frac1q+\frac1{pq^2}.
$$
An approach to compute the mean time necessary to produce any word $w$ in terms of the structure of its prefixes (and an explanation of the formula above) is in the book *DNA, Words And Models* by Robin, Rodolphe, and Schbath. The authors explain why this mean time is the sum of the inverses of the probabilities of each prefix of $w$ which is also a suffix of $w$. When $w=tht$, these prefixes-suffixes are $tht$ and $t$, whose probabilities are $pq^2$ and $q$ respectively, hence the formula above.