# How many times to roll a die before getting $n$ consecutive sixes given $m$ occurences?

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

Given a unbiased dice how to find the average number of rolls required to get $n$ consecutive sixes given already $m$ number of sixes occurred where $m\leq n$. I know how to solve using n consecutive sixes with out any occurrences from this link [How many times to roll a die before getting two consecutive sixes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192177/how-many-times-to-roll-a-die-before-getting-two-consecutive-sixes), can anyone help me finding out no of rolls if any occurrences occured before?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are fairly new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are so far; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them write their answers at an appropriate level. 

Also have a look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/75923

Answer (score 3):

For $m\in\left\{ 0,\cdots,n\right\} $ let $\mu_{m}$ denote the expectation
of number of rolls required to get $n$ consecutive sixes on the moment
that the throwing of exactly $m$ consecutive sixes has just occurred. Then $\mu_{n}=0$
and for $m<n$ we find the recursion formula: 
$$\mu_{m}=1+\frac{1}{6}\mu_{m+1}+\frac{5}{6}\mu_{0}$$ It is based on the observation that with probability $\frac{1}{6}$ by throwing a six we land in the situation of having $m+1$ consecutive sixes and with probability $\frac{5}{6}$ we will have to start all over again.
Substituting $m=0$ leads to $\mu_{0}=6+\mu_{1}$ and substituting
this in the recursion formula gives: $\mu_{m}=6+\frac{1}{6}\mu_{m+1}+\frac{5}{6}\mu_{1}$.

Substituting $m=1$ in this new formula leads to $\mu_{1}=6^{2}+\mu_{2}$ and... Now
wait a minute...

This starts to 'smell' like: $$\mu_{m}=6^{m+1}+\mu_{m+1}$$
doesn't it? Presume this to be true. Then we find:

> $$\mu_{m}=\frac{1}{5}\left(6^{n+1}-6^{m+1}\right)$$

This enables us to actually *prove* that the presumption is correct. For this it is enough
to check that indeed $\mu_{n}=0$ and $\mu_{m}=1+\frac{1}{6}\mu_{m+1}+\frac{5}{6}\mu_{0}$
for $m<n$, which is just a matter of routine.

Note that for $n=2$ we find $\mu_{0}=\frac{1}{5}\left(6^{3}-6\right)=42$
corresponding with the answers on the question that you referred to.