# Expected number of rolls until obtaining a $6$ given that none of the rolls yielded an odd number

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, expected-value

So I have stumbled upon this question recently and though I solved it I'm not sure if it's correct or not.

> A fair $6$-sided die is rolled repeatedly until a $6$ is obtained. Find the
>   expected number of rolls conditioned on the event that none of the
>   rolls yielded an odd number.

**My attempt**:

Let $X$ be the random varibale denoting the no of rolls required until a $6$ is obtained. Without any given condition $X \sim Geom(\frac16)$
But $$\mathbb{P}(\text{obtaining a }6 |  \text{roll does not yield an odd number})= \frac13$$ so, $$X | \text{none of the 
rolls yielded an odd number} \sim Geom\bigl(\frac13\bigr)$$ and hence $$\mathbb{E}(X | \text{none of the 
rolls yielded an odd number})= 3$$

Is this the correct answer? Is there any other approach? Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: @MaxFt so what about my method? Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: See more info here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2779681/expected-number-of-die-rolls-to-get-6-given-that-all-rolls-are-even?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Define random variable $X$ to be the number of rolls until the first 6.  Let $A$ be the event that all rolls yield even numbers.  We want to compute $E(X|A)$.  By conditioning on the first roll $k$ that yields an odd number (if any), we have
$$E(X) = E(X|A) P(A) + \sum_{k \ge 1} E(X|\text{first odd at roll $k$}) P(\text{first odd at roll $k$}).$$
Because $X \sim \text{Geom}(1/6)$, we have $E(X) = 6$.  By conditioning on whether the first roll is in $\{6\}$, $\{2,4\}$, or $\{1,3,5\}$, we have $P(A) = 1(1/6) + P(A)(2/6) + 0(3/6)$, so $P(A) = 1/4$.  Now $$E(X|\text{first odd at roll $k$}) = k + E(X) = k + 6,$$ and $$P(\text{first odd at roll $k$}) = (2/6)^{k-1} (3/6).$$  Substituting everything into the first equation yields $E(X|A) = 3/2$.