# How many times to roll a die before getting two consecutive sixes.

Tags: probability, dice

Andre Nicolas provides a nice solution to this problem in the link below but I am confused by one step:

[How many times to roll a die before getting two consecutive sixes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192177/how-many-times-to-roll-a-die-before-getting-two-consecutive-sixes)

I have pasted his solution below.

I am confused by the equation for b:

I get that b should be 1 if we roll a second six straight after the first but this only happens with probability $\frac{1}{6}?$ Therefore it would seem to me that the equation for b should be:

$$b=1*\frac{1}{6}+\frac{5}{6}a.$$

> Instead of finding the probability distribution, and then the
>   expectation, we can work directly with expectations. That is often a
>   useful strategy.
>
> Let $a$ be the expected *additional* waiting time if we have not just
>   tossed a $6$. At the beginning, we certainly have not just tossed a
>   $6$, so $a$ is the required expectation.   Let $b$ be the expected
>   *additional* waiting time if we have just tossed a $6$.
>
> If we have not just tossed a $6$, then with probability $\frac{5}{6}$
>   we toss a non-$6$ (cost: $1$ toss) and  our expected additional
>   waiting time is still $a$. With probability $\frac{1}{6}$ we toss a
>   $6$ (cost: $1$ toss) and our expected additional waiting time is $b$.
>   Thus $$a=1+\frac{5}{6}a+\frac{1}{6}b.$$ If we have just tossed a $6$,
>   then with probability $\frac{5}{6}$ we toss a non-$6$, and then our
>   expected additional waiting time is $a$. (With probability
>   $\frac{1}{6}$ the game is over.) Thus $$b=1+\frac{5}{6}a.$$ We have
>   two linear equations in two unknowns. Solve for $a$.  We get $a=42$.

Comment: Whether you get a $6$ or not, you need an additional toss at least. In other words, you may also express $b$ as $\displaystyle b = \frac {1} {6} \times 1 + \frac {5} {6} (1 + a)$