# Expected number of dice rolls to get 2 sixes: not geometric?

Tags: probability, expected-value, geometric-distribution

The geometric distribution tells us that when you have independent events and you want to obtain the expected value till you have a success, you know that E[x] = 1/p.

P(2 sixes in a row) = (1/6)(1/6) = 1/36

Since rolling dice is independent trials, why is the expected number of rolls till you get 2 6s not equal to 1/(1/36), or 36? The answer is actually 42.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192177/what-is-the-expected-number-of-times-a-dice-has-to-be-rolled-to-get-two-consecut

Comment: It would have been good to reference that link earlier - it would have saved me typing up a whole wasted answer... I suppose I'll add my text to that link

Comment: $1/36$ is the answer to the question, if I have **two** dice and roll them both, counting this as "one roll", how may times do I expect to roll before the dice both come up $6$ on the same roll? So if I rolled $5,6$ the first time and $6,2$ the second time, I would still have to continue rolling because the two $6$s occurred on different rolls of the two dice. In the question you got the answer $42$ from, after rolling $5$, $6,$ and $6$ you would be finished already.

Comment: If the dice rolls are represented by , say , $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$ then it is NOT true that the event $\{X_1=6,X_2=6\}$ is independent of the event $\{X_1 \neq 6,X_2=6,X_3=6\}$. The "middle" roll $X_2$ forces dependence of the events. Hence, the independence argument falls apart and a different argument is necessary, one that might use Markov chains, or example.