# Find E[N]. (Absorbing States MC)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, dice

Assume we toss a dice until *odd* number appears *four* consecutive times, and in such a case we stop the game. Let $N$ be the total number of times we will toss the dice. Find $E[N]$.

Lets say for states $S=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. Here is the transition matrix for Markov Chain ... 
$$
  \begin{array}{c|ccccc}
      & 0  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
    0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0   & 0   & 0 \\
    1 & 1/2 & 0   & 1/2 & 0   & 0 \\
    2 & 1/2 & 0   & 0   & 1/2 & 0 \\
    3 & 1/2 & 0   & 0   & 0   & 1/2 \\
    4 & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 1
  \end{array}
$$

P.S. or Assume we toss a dice until the number 1 appears for 3 consecutive times, and in such a case we stop the game. Let $N$ be the total number of times we will toss the dice. Find $E[N]$.

Here the transition matrix would be;

$$
  \begin{array}{c|ccccc}
      & 0  & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
    0 & 5/6 & 1/6 & 0   & 0   \\
    1 & 5/6 & 0   & 1/6 & 0   \\
    2 & 5/6 & 0   & 0   & 1/6 \\
    3 & 0   & 0   & 0   & 1   \\
  \end{array}
$$

Comment: Do you require it to be the _same_ odd number all four times?

Comment: Assuming the die is six-sided, you can think of this as tossing a fair coin until four consecutive heads appear. A slight modification of the arguments in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95396/expected-number-of-tosses-for-two-coins-to-achieve-the-same-outcome-for-five-con) post can be made to find $\Bbb E(N)$.

Comment: Try drawing a Markov chain.  Let state $s_i$ be the state where $i$ consecutive odd numbers appears.  The probability of going to state $s_0$ is 1/2 and the probability to proceed to $s_{i+1}$ is 1/2. Then you can trace the paths of length N leading to $s_4$.  Good luck.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27989/time-until-a-consecutive-sequence-of-ones-in-a-random-bit-sequence

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: *that's* why this seemed so familiar.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the matrix that appears in the question, we will use
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}
\tfrac12&\tfrac12&0&0&0\\
\tfrac12&0&\tfrac12&0&0\\
\tfrac12&0&0&\tfrac12&0\\
\tfrac12&0&0&0&\tfrac12\\
0&0&0&0&0\vphantom{\tfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}\tag{1}
$$
A die having thrown $4$ odds will appear in the $5^{\text{th}}$ column only on the roll that it gets there and then is removed. The expected number of rolls will then be the $5^{\text{th}}$ column of
$$
v\sum_{n=0}^\infty nM^n=vM(I-M)^{-2}\tag{2}
$$
where $v=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$, the initial state.

That is, $\mathrm{E}[N]$ is the $5^{\text{th}}$ column of
$$
\begin{align}
&\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\tfrac12&\tfrac12&0&0&0\\
\tfrac12&0&\tfrac12&0&0\\
\tfrac12&0&0&\tfrac12&0\\
\tfrac12&0&0&0&\tfrac12\\
0&0&0&0&0\vphantom{\tfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 16 & 8 & 4 & 2 & 1\vphantom{\tfrac12} \\
 14 & 8 & 4 & 2 & 1\vphantom{\tfrac12} \\
 12 & 6 & 4 & 2 & 1\vphantom{\tfrac12} \\
 8 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 1\vphantom{\tfrac12} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\vphantom{\tfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}^2
\\[6pt]
&=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 416 & 216 & 112 & 58 & 30 \\
 386 & 200 & 104 & 54 & 28 \\
 328 & 170 & 88 & 46 & 24 \\
 216 & 112 & 58 & 30 & 16 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\\[6pt]
&=\begin{bmatrix}
416 & 216 & 112 & 58 & \color{#C00000}{30}
\end{bmatrix}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $\mathrm{E}[N]=30$

---

**Another Approach**

Using the method from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/197998), we use $p=\frac12$ and $n=4$ to get
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}[N]
&=\frac{1-\left(\tfrac12\right)^4}{\left(\tfrac12\right)^4\left(1-\tfrac12\right)}\\[6pt]
&=30\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Validation of the Series**

Equation $(2)$ is simply the power series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\tag{5}
$$
which converges for $|x|<1$, applied to $M$. We need to verify that the series converges when applied to $M$.
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^mnM^n(I-M)^2
&=\sum_{n=0}^mnM^n(I-2M+M^2)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^m(nM^n-2nM^{n+1}+nM^{n+2})\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^mnM^n-2\sum_{n=1}^{m+1}(n-1)M^n+\sum_{n=2}^{m+2}(n-2)M^n\\
&=\left(M+\sum_{n=2}^mnM^n\right)-2\left(mM^{m+1}+\sum_{n=2}^m(n-1)M^n\right)\\
&+\left((m-1)M^{m+1}+mM^{m+2}+\sum_{n=2}^m(n-2)M^n\right)\\
&=M-(m+1)M^{m+1}+mM^{m+2}\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
The characteristic polynomial of $M$ is $P(x)=16x^5-8x^4-4x^3-2x^2-x$ and the absolutely largest root of $P$ is $0.96378098774146265213$. Since this is less than $1$, the series converges. Therefore, we get
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty nM^n(I-M)^2=M\tag{7}
$$
which becomes $(2)$.

Comment: Can you please provide more info about the formula? reference book or article would be helpful. $v\sum_{n=0}^\infty nM^n=vM(I-M)^{-2}$

Comment: @Faheem: I have added a validation of the series.

Comment: If i take the M=[0.5 0.5 0 0 0; 0.5 0 0.5 0 0; 0.5 0 0 0.5 0; 0.5 0 0 0 0.5; 0 0 0 0 1]; The one in question, showing that the state 4 being the absorbing state (represented by 1 on forth row and forth column). If I calculate (I-M)^-2, it results in Inf !!!

Comment: @Faheem: Yes it does; since the bottom row of $I-M$ is all zeros, the determinant is $0$.

Comment: @Faheem: Furthermore, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}M^n=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\ne0$. Also, $\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$.