# Markov Chain (DTMC)

Tags: markov-chains

What is the expected number of times we need to roll a die until we get three consecutive 6's?

I am trying to construct the transition matrix; however, I am not sure how also how to go from here.

Comment: Let's start with just getting to the transition matrix. The important thing is choosing the right state space: you want a dice roll to be one transition between states, you want one state to be the initial state, and you want one state to be the final state. What other state(s) do you need?

Comment: one state that I roll one consecutive 6 and the other state that I roll two consecutive 6's?

Comment: That's right. Now find the transition matrix; since your state space has 4 elements, it should be $4 \times 4$. (Don't worry about transitions from 3 consecutive 6's, that row won't matter.)

Comment: I am a bit confused about contrasting it, my thought of the first row of the 4x4 transition matrix is: 5/6, 1/12, 1/12, 0. Am I on the right track?

Comment: The 5/6 is right, but if you haven't rolled any 6's yet, then you can't get to 2 consecutive 6's in one step. You can only go back to 0 or go to 1. What's the probability of going to 1?

Comment: The probability of going to 1 is 1/6....?

Comment: That's right. Now continue like that.

Comment: so is my matrix just looks like P = [5/6, 1/6, 0, 0; 5/6, 0, 1/6, 0; 5/6, 0, 0, 1/6; 0, 0, 0, 1]?

Comment: That's right. Now you should have learned an approach based on the total expectation formula for solving your original problem.

Comment: Do we use the E(E(X|Y))? But three of them...I'm not sure I know how to do it :/

Comment: That part is straightforward, and can be taught by me just as well as any book: define $\tau(x)=\inf \{ t : X(t)=3 \mid X(0)=x\}$ and $r(x)=E[\tau(x)]$. Then the total expectation formula says $r(x)=1+\sum_{y \in S} P(x,y) r(y)$. Adjoin this to the boundary condition $r(3)=0$ and solve the resulting system of four linear equations in four unknowns. Then extract the information you actually want from the solution.

Comment: I will have a go, thank you so much for the help! Really appreciate it.

Comment: See here as well: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487911/what-is-the-pmf-of-rolling-a-die-until-obtaining-three-consecutive-6s/1491528#1491528